# Kill a whole process tree regardless different GIDs

Tags: process, signals

I am having issues with process control using the signals available to the process abstraction. In the example below you can see there is a `perl` script which is the parent of the whole tree with a `group i.d.` of `25235`. This `GID` is inherited by all the children. However one of the children, a shell with the `PID` of `4205`, starts a new `GID` of `4205`.

The reason I am setting a new group id for this branch of the process tree is there are times I want to run `kill -9 -4205` killing the sh process and all its children with that share the same `GID` without affecting the rest of the process tree. I can then restart the shell process and its children. The problem I am having is when I need to kill the whole tree starting with `perl` script (the parent) If I run `kill -9 -25235` (main `group i.d.`) or `kill -9 4678` (parents `PID`) this will kill the whole tree except the branch which has a different group id. These processes will be re-parented to init.

Is there a way to kill the whole tree regardless of the different `GIDs`? I suspect `session ids` may come to play but I have not been able to figure that out if so.

process tree example:

```
perl(4678,25235)─┬─sc_serv(4685,25235)─┬─{sc_serv}(4691,25235)
                 │                     ├─{sc_serv}(4693,25235)
                 │                     └─{sc_serv}(4694,25235)
                 └─sh(4205,4205)─┬─ffmpeg(4207,4205)
                                 └─vlc(4208,4205)─┬─{vlc}(4217,4205)
                                                  ├─{vlc}(4219,4205)
                                                  └─{vlc}(4296,4205)
```